# Overriding results in Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, japplet

I want to develop a Java Applet which shows visualization of Sorting. So I have written code like this...

```
public class SortNumbersGUI extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<Integer> randomList;
    JLabel numberLabel;
    JButton sortButton;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        randomList = MyRandom.myRandom();
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        sortButton = new JButton("Sort");
        sortButton.setBounds(50, 0, 50, 10);
        sortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Collections.sort(randomList);
                removeAll();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        this.add(sortButton);
        super.init();
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int y = 20;

        for (Integer i : randomList) {
            g.drawString(i.toString(), 0, y + 10);
            g.fillRect(20, y, (i * 10) / 10, 5);
            y = y + 20;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I am facing two problems here..

1. Sort button, which is JButton is not always visible. When i am placing mouse cursor over that sort button place then only it is appearing.
2. The results are overriding when I am calling repaint() method. As the bellow image

[Result Image](https://flic.kr/p/q1KSLF) (As I don't have reputation I am pasting the image link.)

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // ..
```

Should be:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // paints **BG**, border etc.
    // ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are overridding paint instead of paintComponent, and also you are not calling super.paint/Component (also a good practice, though possibly not 100% necessary here).

Because of how you've overridden paint(), you button is not getting automatically painted when the JApplet is painted

Comment: *"you are overridding paint instead of paintComponent"*  Unlike `JComponent`, top level containers like `JFrame` and `JApplet` have no `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  (One of the various reasons it is considered better to do custom painting in a `JPanel` then add the panel to the frame or applet..)